# Why is the MATCH function is not resolving my lookup array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In Excel 2010, I am using two Excel tables. One table (ActiveDS) has a single column and contains a list of our active data sources. The other table (ApproverRole) has a number of columns, including a Clean Data Source column.

I want to determine if an entry in the Approver Role table has a matching entry in the ActiveDS table. My current formula is

```
=IFERROR((MATCH([@[Clean Data Source]], ActiveDataS[Active Data  Source],0)), "Not Active")
```

I'm getting an error on that formula. When I step through the formula, the error is on resolving the "ActiveDataS[Active Data Source]" argument in the MATCH function. It converts it to the cell references just fine. 
[image: Screen shot of error showing the conversion to cell references marked as going to evaluate to an error]

What is going on here?

Edited: I'm getting the #N/A error for every item. The error is not in resolving the full formula, it is in resolving the lookup array.

Comment: What error do you get? N/A would indicate there's no match in the lookup range. "I get an error" is never enough information. Error messages are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

In your question's text, you show the Table being named `ActiveDS` but in the formula, there is a space:  `Active DS`.

While there will never be confirmation from a 7yo question, this difference is enough for Excel to fail when trying to resolve that parameter.

Personally, I ALWAYS use that naming convention (it has a name, but it eludes me), the capital letter starting each word, and otherwise being essentially as one learned to write things in first grade:  "ThisColumnComesFirst" as an example. It is much easier to type than inserting bothersome underscore characters which require the Shift key and more readable too (usually... "ActiveDSCafeteria" in which both D and S are capitalized as an abbreviation, and then C in the following word... these crop up and are one area in which it is not the best).

However, it has one huge drawback:  we are so used to inserting the spaces when typing separate words that it can happen that a space is inserted when it does not belong.

When using the convention, getting errors that are, or seem to be, stemming from not resolving an address should trigger you to immediately look for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

`#N/A` means the items don't match. Pick a cell that you feel has a match in the ActiveData table. Use a formula along the lines of

```
=MySheet!A1='Active DS'!A1
```

Replace references with the two cells that you KNOW are a match. You'll find they are not. Clean the data.